# Oracle: updating column IF ONLY it is not in condition of Merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, data-warehouse

I'm having trouble with this Oracle Merge query.

```
    merge into NEW_DOCTORS NP
    USING OLD_DOCTORS MD
    on (MD.SSN=NP.SSN OR MD.NPI=NP.NPI OR MD.PIN=NP.PIN)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    NP.othervalues=MD.othervalues
    NP.PIN/SSN/NPI=MD.PIN/SSN/NPI (**update two of these three that did not return TRUE in the above ON condition)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    insert(NP.SSN,NP.NPI,NP.PIN,NP.other_values)
    values(MD.SSN,MD.NPI,MD.PIN,MD.other_values)
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

EDIT: I'm asking because I read somewhere that fields that are in the ON condition can't be updated. However I'm not sure if the author was talking only in context of the field that evaluates true or for all fields. I'm hoping there's someone who might have an idea about this, as well as any workarounds.

Comment: What if update all of them, just overwrite the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN ...` :

```
UPDATE SET 
NP.othervalues=MD.othervalues
,NP.PIN = CASE WHEN (MD.SSN=NP.SSN OR MD.NPI=NP.NPI) THEN MD.PIN ELSE NP.PIN END
,--add here the 2 others
```

This means, when you have `MD.SSN=NP.SSN OR MD.NPI=NP.NPI` true, then update `NP.PIN` with `MD.PIN` else let the same value `NP.PIN`

Or you can do 3 differents MERGE, so it will be more readable.

**EDIT**

Thinking about it, if you update only when this is not the same value (cause it will join only on same value) you can directly update them with the MD table value.

Do that :

```
NP.othervalues=MD.othervalues
,NP.PIN=MD.PIN
,NP.SSN=MD.SSN
,NP.NPI=MD.NPI
```

If they match, the update will keep same value, if not it will update the value.

Comment: If I remember correctly you are not allowed to update fields that are part of the ON condition. Since I'm using an OR here and some of these conditions are not evaluated, I was hoping to learn if they can still be updated. I don't have the chance to check right now but I believe at least one of the 3 assignments that you did might give an error..

Comment: You might be right, I think they are many solution, try to use the trick of 3 different MERGE. Solution depends on what is ur data content, anyway if you are facing a particular issue, I'll try to help you.

Comment: I ended up going with 3 different merges. It's not pretty, but it works.